# do_shortcodes() isn't working

Tags: plugins, themes, shortcode, customization

I'm making a homepage template for my theme and I want to call a plugin, namely royalslider.
Surely

```
do_shortcode('[gallery id= "1"]');
```

Should do the trick?

Comment: Is your homepage an actual post/page containing attached images? And you're calling do_shortcode inside the main loop?

Comment: is that the official shortcode used by royalsider?

Comment: @TomJNowell
Nope - it's just a home.php file. Can do_shortcode only be called in a loop?

Comment: @Michael Yes it is.

Comment: The gallery shortcode makes no sense without a post as its current context, you cant just call shortcodes anywhere, how would the gallery know what images to use?

Comment: @TomJNowell Fair enough. I'm very new to WP development, alot of stuff still boggles me. Is there anyway to initiate this plugin anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the preload skin option selected in the Royalslider options

Answer (score 0):

`do_shortcode()` returns output and doesn't print anything. I'm often caught by this. Often the solution is to just echo the function's output:

```
echo do_shortcode('[gallery id="1"]');
```

You should also remove the space after `id=`.

Finally, make sure that you have images attached to the Post with the ID 1, which is what that shortcode would normally output.

Answer (score 0):

`do_shortcode` needs to be called inside a post loop. Otherwise you're left with the problem of:

- Which gallery
- Which images
- etc

You're using this plugin right? http://codecanyon.net/item/royalslider-touch-content-slider-for-wordpress/700256?ref=Semenov&ref=Semenov&clickthrough_id=84484598&redirect_back=true

I'd suggest you make your gallery in a post, and then have a post in a featured category, and display that ( with the shortcode in the content ). use a WP_Query loop with a limit of 1 post to prevent interfering with the main loop

e.g.

```
<div id="featured-post">
    <?php
    $q = new WP_Query('category_name' => 'featured','posts_per_page' => 1);
    if($q->have_posts()){
        while($q->have_posts()){
            $q->the_post();
            the_content();
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        ?><p>no featured post found!</p><?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

This also gives you the extra flexibility of changing your mind or updating the slider, or using a static image, or having a text based feature